# How to embed c# code in javascript on cshtml MVC3 Razor page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

how would I do the equivalent of this embedded in JavaScript on an MVC2 aspx page:

`if (('<%= Model.SomeFunctionEnabled %>' == 'True')` and also a whole function code block on a Razor view page (cshtml) in MVC3?

Something like :

```
@{
    foreach(var d in Model.Employees)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Which works fine when embedded in the HTML part of the view page.
Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Why testing on the client side when you could do this on the server side and include the javascript to act accordingly if the test succeeds:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    @if (Model.SomeFunctionEnabled) {
        <text>
        // Put your javascript code here
        alert('the function is enabled');
        </text>
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Darin, sometimes I want to keep the display code in the view. However, I've realised that its just VS' syntax highlighter which doesn't work properly for this - its actually fine!

Comment: @stan4th, OK, but in your example in the `if` statement you were mixing server side code with javascript making it difficult to read. That's why I suggested you an improvement.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - I want to render some inline HTML like below...`<script language="javascript">
    if (isOutside) {
    @{   //Some HTML inline tags should be here.
                
    }
    else {
    }
</script>` Can you make corrections. I am right now not able to add HTML tags inside If conditions.

Comment: @SMC, I don't understand what you are asking. What HTML tags inside a `<script>` element?

Comment: @SMC, still this doesn't answer my question: `What HTML tags inside a <script> element`? Normally HTML tags are placed in the markup, not in script elements. The script element is used for javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute the logic in JavaScript:

```
if ('@Model.SomeFunctionEnabled' == 'True') {
}
```

But this results in a condition that always evaluates to the same outcome. So you are better with Darin's answer to do the whole testing on the server.

If your test is however something dynamic like this, that cannot be executed on the server. You can get the contents of your C# variable by using a `@` sign.

```
@{
    var elementID = GetMyGeneratedElementID();
}

<div id="@elementID">...</div>
<script>
   function MyAmazingJavascriptElementHandler() {
       if ($("#@elementID").SomeTest()) {
          DoMyAmazingJavascript();
       }
   }
</script>
```